# Which std::string constructor am I using?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I see std::string has many constructors https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/.

But which one am I using when I do:

```
const char* s = "abc";
string str(s);
```

I bet is:

> from c-string (4) string (const char* s);

> (4) from c-string
> Copies the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s.

But isn't a c-string always null terminated? That `s` isn't according to my ide/debugger (Qt Creator on macOS).

Am I on undefined behavior territory?

Should I instead do the following?

```
const char* s = "abc";
string str(s, 3);
```

Comment: `But isn't a c-string always null terminated?` Yes. `That s isn't according to my ide/debugger` It is. Your debugger just doesn't show the terminator.

Comment: The folks who monitor **C** questions won't like the `c` tag on this question, because it isn't a **C** question.

Comment: @tkausl When I do `char s[] = "abc"` then is shows an extra `\0`. I'm wondering why the difference, do you know?

Comment: *"Am I on undefined behavior territory?..."* No, not at all.

Comment: `"abc"` is an array of 4 `char`; the fourth element is `'\0'`.

Comment: Your debugger has no way of knowing how many chars are pointed to by the `char*` (so it displays until the null terminator) but it does know how many chars are in the `char[4]` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That `s` isn't according to my ide/debugger (Qt Creator on macOS).

Your debugger is likely just not showing the terminator. String literals are always null terminated. You can see it for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (char ch : "abc") {
        std::cout << +ch << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
97
98
99
0
```

But if you create the string manually, you are responsible for the terminator:

```
char cs1[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};        // not null terminated
char cs2[] {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }; // properly terminated
std::string s1(cs1);               // undefined behavior
std::string s2(cs2);               // OK
```

Comment: I think you pointed the case I was trying to, but due to my ide/debugger (to some degree) I didn't put it appropriately. Non null terminated array argument to string constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> But isn't a c-string always null terminated?

Yes, string literals are null terminated. The debugger/ide might not be showing the null terminator in your case.

From [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> The type of an unprefixed string literal is `const char[N]`, where `N` is the size of the string in code units of the execution narrow encoding (until C++23)ordinary literal encoding (since C++23), **including the null terminator**.

---

> Am I on undefined behavior territory?

No, not at all. Both of the given snippets are well-formed.

Comment: The so called `c-string` and the so called `string literal`, are those the same thing?

Comment: @KcFnMi Yes, string literal is also known as "c-string". They're two names for the same thing. In c++ there is "c++ string"(aka simply "string") that we can create with `std::string`.

Comment: And how do we call it when it's not null-terminated? When we create the string manually, as @Ayxan_Haqverdili mentioned. Then it's not c-string anymore?

Comment: @KcFnMi By "call" do you mean like "function/constructor call" or did you mean in the context of "how do we name it when there is no null terminator"?

Comment: @KcFnMi If you mean the latter then it is just called as "non null terminated array".

Comment: I mean how to name it.

Comment: @KcFnMi When it's not null-terminated we name it as a "non-null terminated char array".

Answer (score 1):

A string literal like "abc" is always null-terminated. You can use your first example. Typically you would write it like this though:

```
std::string str = "abc";
```

Edit, see comment below: <s>Inside the string object str 'abc' it will most likely not be null-terminated (until you eventually call str.c_str()).</s>

Comment: no, it will be null terminated inside the string - this was a change in c++11